# File doesn't have full rights when uploading from windows nfs client

Tags: server, permissions, mount, nfs

Firstly I would like to say that my experience with ubuntu is completely beginner level. I have an old 32 bit machine running ubuntu server 16.04.6 LTS as a nfs host and a windows 10 machine as a nfs client. When I log into MobaXterm with ssh and create a folder in my mounted directory it shows full drwxrwxrwx access, but when I create a folder via nfs the folder only has drw-rw---- access.
Here's my /etc/exports configuration

```
/mnt/storage 192.168.8.144(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

I have created DWORD entries in my registry to match anonuid and anongid. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's some screenshots. [full access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ3Uu.png) [no access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTOkZ.png)